# Understanding scala syntax trait

Tags: scala

I am reading about scalatest and I am coming across this syntax a lot

```
trait Sample {
  self : FlatSpec =>

}
```

What does this mean? Please explain with an example

Comment: self-type. Basically meaning, the entity which implements this trait is also another Trait, but this trait itself is not that Trait (so you shouldn't extend it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [self-type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html). It means trait `Sample` can access all members from `FlatSpec`, but when you create any instance based on this trait you must `mixin` (combine) this instance with instance of `FlatSpec`. You are not able to create an instance of `Sample` without providing implementation of `FlatSpec` because `Sample` may use methods from there.

This may look a bit like inheritance but it's not. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224932/difference-between-trait-inheritance-and-self-type-annotation) answer

Note: `self` is just a reference to current object not a syntax element. You can use any word instead of `self`.