# Suggestion dealing with multiple traits and profile combinations in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I have a situation where I have several traits with each trait containing a set of methods. I have now to expose these functionalities to the external world through profiles. For example., a basic profile will be another trait, but this contains just the methods a and 2 from trait 1, methods 4 and 5 from trait 2 etc.,I can create these profiles as a new trait and repeat the method implementation, but how can I reuse the already defined methods in my trait and just create the profile traits more elegantly? For example.,

```
trait InternalTrait1 {
  def method1(int: Int): Int
  def method2(int: Int): Int
}

trait InternalTrait2 {
  def method3(int: Int): Int
  def method4(int: Int): String
}
```

I would now like to have:

```
    trait BasicProfile {
      this: InternalTrait1 with InternalTrait2 =>

      def method2(int: Int): Int = super.method2(int)
      def method4(int: Int): String = super.method4(int)
    }
```

I want to refer the method2 and method4 from Trait1 and Trait2 respectively. Any ideas? Self traits come to my mind, but not sure if that is a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you introduce a couple of traits more (like `Method2Doer` and `Method4Doer` below)?

```scala
trait Method2Doer {
  def method2(int: Int): Int
}

trait Method4Doer {
  def method4(int: Int): String
}
  
trait InternalTrait1 extends Method2Doer {
  def method1(int: Int): Int
}

trait InternalTrait2 extends Method4Doer {
  def method3(int: Int): Int
}

trait BasicProfile extends Method2Doer with Method4Doer
```

---

If none of the traits are in IS-A relation and you'd prefer not to introduce new traits then you can try to replace inheritance with composition (HAS-A relation)

```
trait BasicProfile {
  val internalTrait1Inst: InternalTrait1
  val internalTrait2Inst: InternalTrait2
    
  def method2(int: Int): Int = internalTrait1Inst.method2(int)
  def method4(int: Int): String = internalTrait2Inst.method4(int)
}
```

or

```scala
trait BasicProfile {
  val internalTraitsInst: InternalTrait1 with InternalTrait2

  def method2(int: Int): Int = internalTraitsInst.method2(int)
  def method4(int: Int): String = internalTraitsInst.method4(int)
}
```

---

In principle you can use structural types

```scala
trait BasicProfile { this: {def method2(int: Int): Int; def method4(int: Int): String} =>
    
}
```

Comment: No, this is not a good idea.I have in my InternalTrait1 around 20 methods and BasicProfile would be with Method1 and Method2, but BasicProfile2 would be Method3 and Method4, so that means I end up having one trait per method, which is the worst I could do!

Comment: @joesan Why having one trait per method is bad if you actually have many behaviors and that's what traits represent, behaviors? Besides that, how are you going to call methods? You write `def method2(int: Int): Int` in `InternalTrait1` and `BasicProfile` but actually those methods are different. Every method has one more parameter besides `(int: Int ...)` i.e. `this`. What exactly "refering" methods mean? You can call `basicProfileInstance.method2(...)` and `internalTrait1Instance.method2(...)`. Where do you get `internalTrait1Instance` in `BasicProfile`?

Comment: @joesan Try to think about your traits in OOP way via IS-A relashionship.

Comment: @joesan Just in case, if your methods doesn't change `this` (i.e. are static) then traits should be objects and then you can import methods: `object Internal1 { def method2 }` `object BasicProfile { import Internal._ }`

Comment: I just want to mix in some of the methods from some traits into one trait which in my case is the BasicProfile and I then implement the BasicProfile as a concrete class.

Comment: I mentioned that I will have to come up with 20 different profiles and this would mean that I need to have shit loads of traits with single methods and this is the worst I could do! I have some traits that has around 30 methods, so that decomposes to 30 individual traits and it simply is not a good idea!

Comment: I have edited my post, I'm looking for something like that, but it fails compilation saying that the implementing class of the BasicProfile lacks definitions for method1 and method3

Comment: @joesan In principle you can use structural types (see update)

Comment: Ok, can you please elaborate on the structural types a bit?

Comment: @joesan They use runtime reflection. https://www.baeldung.com/scala/structural-types https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Structural_Typing https://nrinaudo.github.io/scala-best-practices/unsafe/structural_types.html https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-structural.html

Comment: I'm not sure how Structural types might be of help here.

Comment: None of the porposed solutions here are elegant. It causes more damage in the codebase than benefit. I'm looking for a trait that can take several methods from a mix of other traits and ignore some other methods.

Comment: @joesan You're trying to abuse OOP. That's why there can't be an elegant solution. There can't be such thing as "take several methods from traits". `def method2(int: Int): Int` in `InternalTrait1` is actually `def method2(/* this1: InternalTrait1 */, int: Int): Int`, `def method4(int: Int): String` in `InternalTrait2` is actually `def method4(/*this2: InternalTrait2 */, int: Int): String`. You can't call them in `BasicProfile` without providing `this1`, `this2`. Either you provide these instances explicitly or you take current `BasicProfile`'s `this` ...

Comment: @joesan ... but then you need inheritance (either with extending or with self-types, never mind), which you're trying to break. If we're lazy to refactor code creating new traits then some code generation can be used (macros, source preprocessors, reflection).

Comment: I very much appreciate the help on this. I was wondering if self traits in Scala could be leveraged, but I realized that at construction time of my concrete class, it would fail compilation and hence I have to now follow your original advice to reverse the order. Have BasicProfile as super trait and the other traits thaz support BasicProfile just inherit it!

Comment: @joesan Yeah, self-types is also inheritance, just at a different place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224932 There's no magic, anyway you have to provide `this1`, `this2` somehow in order to call the methods.