# Refactoring to higher order function in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and wondering if I can somehow refactor this code using Scala's support for function literals, higher order functions etc

Because there is no relationship between a Competition and a Team, I don't see how this is possible. I guess I could add a trait to Competition and Team that would include the name property and it would then be possible.

Any other alternatives?

```
class CompetitionDao extends BaseDao[Competition]{

  def retrieveAllCompetitionNames(): java.util.List[String] = {
    val competitions: java.util.List[_ <: Competition] = getDao().queryForAll()
    val competitionNames: java.util.List[String] = new ArrayList();
    for (competition <- competitions) competitionNames.add(competition.name)
    competitionNames
  } 

}

class TeamDao extends BaseDao[Team]{

  def retrieveAllTeamNames(): java.util.List[String] = {
    val teams: java.util.List[_ <: Team] = getDao().queryForAll()
    val teamNames: java.util.List[String] = new ArrayList();
    for (team <- teams) teamNames.add(team.name)
    teamNames
  }  
}
```

Comment: How about def retrieveAllXNames = getDao().queryForAll().map(_.name) ?

Comment: Not sure that works, just tried it

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here. What is `getDao().quaryForAll()`? It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, but I agree with Enrique, this should be a one-liner with native Scala collections. Also, you can automatically convert between Scala and Java collections with `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could introduce a `trait` and use `map` like Enrique suggested:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

trait NameRetrieval[T <: { def name: String }] { self: BaseDao[T] =>
  def retrieveAllNames = getDao.queryForAll.map(_.name)
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
object TeamDao extends BaseDao[Team] with NameRetrieval[Team]
```

### Edit

The `[T <: { def name:String }]` means that the `NameRetrieval` trait can be used for any type that has a an element called `name` of type `String`. To find out more about that notation search for 'Scala structural types'.

With the `self: BaseDao[T]` I say that this trait can only be used in combination with a `BaseDao` that has the same type for `T`. This allows me to freely use the `getDao` method because I know for sure it's available. A similar pattern is used in the [Cake Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172188/understanding-scalas-cake-pattern), so you can check that out for more information.

Comment: that's quite elegant, i like that

Comment: Can you add some information on what {def name: String} does or what it is needed for? Likewise for the self variable

Comment: @DJ180 the term you need to search for is "structural type". Here it means "any T that has a `name` method returning a String". `self` is a "self type", which means the trait can only be mixed in to the specified type, thus making the members of that type available. Also, `JavaConversions` is semi-deprecated: use `JavaConverters` instead... although if you're actually trying to return a `java.util.List` be aware that this answer uses Scala collections, so it would be more efficient to use neither.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
object DAO{
  def getNames: String => List[String] = { from =>
    from match {
      case "competition" => Competition.getDao().queryForAll().map(_.name)
      case "team" => Team.getDao().queryForAll().map(_.name)
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

calling this would be as easy as

```
val temNames : List[String] = DAO.getNames("team")
```