# Why can't I specify a trait's subclass?

Tags: scala, traits

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> trait T extends A { val t = 1 }
defined trait T

//why can I do this?
scala> class B extends T
defined class B

scala> new B
res0: B = B@2e9c76

scala> res0.t
res1: Int = 1
```

I thought that when you write `trait T extends A`, it makes it so you can only put trait `T` on a class that is a subclass of `A`. Why can I put it on `B`, then? Is this only for when you mix it in? Why is this not possible when declaring the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "it makes it so you can only put trait
>   T on a class that is a subclass of A"

The feature you want is a self-type annotation. See also Daniel Sobral's answer to this question : [What is the difference between self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) --> look for the links to dependancy-injection and cake-pattern.

```
trait A { def t: Int }
trait B {
  this: A => // requires that a concrete implementation mixes in from A
  def t2: Int = t // ...and therefore we can safely access t from A
}

// strangely this doesn't work (why??)
def test(b: B): Int = b.t

// however this does
def test2(b: B): Int = b.t2

// this doesn't work (as expected)
class C extends B

// and this conforms to the self-type
class D extends B with A { def t = 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply confused about what a trait is. Saying `class B extends T` simply means that you're "mixing in" the functionality of the trait to the class definition of B. So, everything defined in T or it's parent classes and traits, is available in B.

Comment: Right, but `trait T extends A` is supposed to only allow you to mixin the trait to class A. It works as intended if you try doing `new B with T` - it won't let you.

Comment: No, `trait T extends A` is *not* supposed to only allow you to mixin the trait to class A. It is adding in the functionality of the class A to the trait T. So T has the functionality (methods and fields) of class A and anything you have defined in T. When you say `class B extends T`, you're bringing in everything from T *and* A.

Comment: @ThomasLockney You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854941/why-can-a-scala-trait-extend-a-class

I think this is what reguy was referring to

Answer (score 0):

What you can’t do is:

```
scala> class A2
defined class A2

scala> class B extends A2 with T
<console>:8: error: illegal inheritance; superclass A2
 is not a subclass of the superclass A
 of the mixin trait T
       class B extends A2 with T
                               ^
```

Actually, writing `class B extends T` is the same as writing `class B extends A with T`.