# scala: reuse subclass implementation as a subclass of two different classes?

Tags: scala, class-design, traits

To simplify my actual code let's say there are two classes, one a subclass of the other:

```
class Chair {
   val canFold = false;
   // ...
}

class FoldableChair extends Chair {
   val canFold = true;
   // ...
}
```

and in my implementation I will have potentially hundreds of other subclasses of Chair or FoldableChair:

```
class Armchair extends ... {}
class DeckChair extends ... {} 
//... etc
```

For each of these subclasses, suppose each one has a lengthy implementation but I want to be able to have it sometimes extend Chair and sometimes extend FoldableChair - without duplicating the code. I'd like to do so without having the subclass itself be extended. Is this possible somehow? Do I need to use traits to do this?

I'd also like to be able to create particular instances of a subclass which sometimes extend Chair and sometimes extend FoldableChair, but that choice is made when instantiating it. Is this possible too? Thanks!

Edit: to clarify, what I really want is this:

```
class Armchair extends Chair {}

class ArmchairFoldable extends FoldableChair {}
```

but the implementation of Armchair and ArmchairFoldable are exactly the same. That is, I'd like to not duplicate their implementations.

Comment: I recommend you to read this article: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use an implementation trait; i.e., a trait that you mix in with a class and that provides additional members with their implementation.

Example:

```
class Chair {
   // you can use a def rather than a val as it's constant and
   // and doesn't need to occupy a field
   def canFold = false

   // ...
}

class FoldableChair extends Chair {
   override def canFold = true
   // ...
}

trait Extensible extends Chair {
    // this trait extends Chair to mean that it is only
    // applicable to Chair or subclasses of Chair
    def extend = /* ... */
}

class FoldableExtensibleChair extends FoldableChair with Extensible
```

Then you can write:

```
val a = new Chair // bare-bones chair

// decide at creation time that this one is extensible
val b = new Chair with Extensible

val c = new FoldableChair // non extensible

// use predefined class which already mixes in Extensible
val d = new FoldableExtensibleChair
```

Comment: Rather than `trait Extensible extends Chair` to enforce that `Extensible` only applies to `Chair`, isn't it customary to use a self-type?  `trait Extensible { self: Chair => ... }`  Not 100% sure of the trade-offs.  Just asking.

Comment: @overthink Yes, it is customary to use self types in this kind of situation.

Comment: The `extends Chair` style is used in Bill Venners's article linked by Frank Thomas and also appears more prominently in the Programming in Scala book. See that question, for which Daniel provided a very nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Comment: philippe this doesn't do quite what i want because in my case i want to have a 3rd subclass (Armchair in the edited question) that sometimes inherits from Chair and sometimes from FoldableChair. but i don't want to duplicate the two implementations. and also i want Armchair to subclass from Chair and but particular instances of Armchair can also subclass from FoldableChair.