# What is more Scala idiomatic: trait TraitA extends TraitB or trait TraitA { self: TraitB => }

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, self-type

Apart from the inheritance aspect, is there a difference between the following class templates:

```
1| trait TraitA extends TraitB

2| trait TraitA { self: TraitB => }
```

I would like to split responsibilities between `TraitA` and `TraitB` but the former cannot function without the latter.

**How would you express this intent?** To me solution [2] would be the more natural approach. However I do not want to put the burden on implementers mixing in what needs to be mixed in anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between scala self-types and trait subclasses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My preference is generally [1] because, as you say, the implementor is not burdened to mix in (a sub-type of) `TraitB`. Perhaps [2] is preferable if, for some reason, it is desirable *not* to inherit the concrete implementations in `TraitB` and force the implementor to make a choice among sub-types of `TraitB`. Still, [1] is just as flexible.

I tend to use [2] only where necessary, such as when the type isn't a known class or trait,

```
// Here, Matrix cannot extend type parameter Repr
trait Matrix[+Repr <: Matrix[Repr]] { self: Repr =>
  ...
}
```

*Update.* Here's another minor difference,

```
trait B
trait A { self: B => }
def g(ab: A): B = ab // Type mismatch: found A, required B
```

It's <del>a little annoying</del> *an optional restriction* not to be able to use `A` as a `B`, even though the type is incorporated.

Comment: Speaking about your update. I think that "little annoyance" is quite useful to let one express that an `A` "cooperates with" but at the same time "is not" a `B`. For me that's kind of like private vs. public inheritance respectively.

Comment: Historically, the motivation for self-type annotation is the first difference—at least, that's how this feature is motivated in the paper *Scalable Component Abstractions* by Odersky&Zenger (which you can find on Google Scholar, if interested).