# why self-type class can declare class

Tags: scala

I know Scala can only mixin traits, it makes sense for dependency injection and cake pattern. My question is why I can still declare a class which need another "class" but not trait.

Code:

```
class C
class D { self : C =>}
```

This is still complied successfully. I thought it should failed compiled, because at this point how can new instance D (C is class not trait).

**Edit:**

when try to instantiate D:

new D with C //compilation fail class C needs to be a trait to be mixed in.

Comment: You missed out trying to actually create an instance of D, do that and see what happens.

Comment: The type of `self` is `D with C`. I'm not sure if there's a use case besides documentation.

Comment: that is my question, if create an instance of D, there is an compilation error. new D with C
<console>:10: error: class C needs to be a trait to be mixed in
              new D with C

Comment: Dzanvu provided a good answer.  Note that traits are essentialy the same as classes without initialization capability.  Self type definition can be useful to implement mutual dependency between a class that extends a trait with self-type set to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly make `class D` to `extends C` as follows:

```
class C
class D extends C { self: C => }
```

Furthermore, you can refer to the post [Does a class with a self type of another class make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274106/does-a-class-with-a-self-type-of-another-class-make-sense), which explains this problem clearly.