# Using this keyword to inherit?

Tags: scala, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between scala self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

From [example in scalatest site](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests). There is one particular thing I don't really understand

```
trait FunSuiteStackBehaviors { 
                   this: FunSuite => //This line
                         def a() {}
                         def b() {}
}

class StackFunSuite extends FunSuite with FunSuiteStackBehaviors {}
```

As far as I understand, it seems like they try to assign some defs into a trait. But what does `this: FunSuite =>` part do ? I tried to use extends FunSuite instead like

```
trait FunSuiteStackBehaviors extends FunSuite { 
                         def a() {}
                         def b() {}
}

class StackFunSuite extends FunSuite with FunSuiteStackBehaviors {}
```

and I still end up with same result. Are they the same thing ?

Comment: It's a self type.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-type

Comment: Hmm. those question doesn't come up when I try to search. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

the this: => XXXX is called a self type annotation http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124
Basically, you're specifying the type of "this" (current object) to the type specified. Kind of a "cast from the inside"

Answer (score 0):

`this: FunSuite =>` is called self type annotation. There is nothing special about `"this"`  Both snippets are equivalent. [Here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalasTypeSystem.html)  [is](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ApplicationDesign.html#SelfTypeAnnotationsAndAbstractTypeMembers) some discussion on its rationale. In short self type annotation helps to signify `compositional` nature rather than `IS-A` relation.