# Best practice for defining multiple traits that add behaviour to classes that implement a particular trait

Tags: scala, traits

Say I have a number of `trait`s that each add some behaviour to classes that extend `Actor`.

They each require a small subset of the methods on `Actor`. Is it ok for them all to extend `Actor` like this?

```
trait A extends Actor {
  def doAThing = { ... }
}
trait B extends Actor {
  def doBThing = { ... }
}
trait C extends Actor {
  def doCThing = { ... }
}

class D extends Actor with A with B with C
```

Or should each trait define the methods it needs from `Actor` as abstract methods such that they are supplied by the final, concrete class, which is the only one that will then extend `Actor`?

Comment: See [What is the difference between scala self-types and trait subclasses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses). That's probably what are you looking for.

Comment: I didn't know about self-types at all - if you think this question is a different enough route to the same answer, then post it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance

```
trait A extends Actor
```

means that `A` is `Actor`. The other way is to use `self-types`

```
trait B {
  self: Actor =>
}
```

means that `B` requires `Actor` to be mixed in.

See [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) for details.