# generic trait taking a class and it's companion object as a type parameter

Tags: scala, generics

So I want to have a generic trait take as a type parameter a class with a companion object that inherits from a specific base class and refer to both the companion object and the class itself. So,

```
abstract class BaseModel[T] {
  def all: Seq[T]
}

case class Customer(email: String, password: String)

object Customer extends BaseModel[Customer]

// This trait is my issue
trait BaseCrud[T] { 
  def table[T](f: T => String): String = {
    T.all.map(f _).mkString("")
  }
}

object Controller with BaseCrud {
  def foo = table(_.email)
}
```

I had some solutions to that trait that were closer but I distilled it down so you can see what I am trying to do.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

So I went with solution from Frank below, but I did manage to solve my initial puzzle. Though, in this case the solution was a bit ugly I'll include it here for completeness sake.

```
abstract class BaseModel[T] {
  def all: Seq[T] = Seq()
}

case class Customer(email: String, password: String)

object Customer extends BaseModel[Customer]

trait BaseCrud[T, U <: BaseModel[T]] { 
  def table(f: T => String)(implicit obj: U): String = {
    obj.all.map(f(_)).mkString("")
  }
}

object Controller extends BaseCrud[Customer, Customer.type] {
  implicit val model = Customer
  def foo = table(_.email)
}
```

So the type parameters changed to BaseCrud and the implicit was added to BaseCrud.table and implemented in Controller.model. I also fixed all my typos. I found it interesting Customer.type seems to be the type of the companion object.

Answer (score 7):

There's a bunch of problems in your code.. let's tackle it one after the other:

- `def table[T](...` note that this `T` overwrites the original type parameter for the scope of the method. Not what you want really, so just omit it and make this `def table(...`
- `object Controller with BaseCrud {` contains two more mistakes:

  1. it has to be `extends` not `with`. The latter is only used after you already extended from some base-class/trait.
  2. `BaseCrud` requires a type parameter that you have to specify here, so something like `BaseCrud[Customer]`
- and finally, to answer your actual question: There is a huge difference between a *type* parameter `T` and a companion *object*. They are inherently different things, so you cannot access the companion object via `T.something`. Instead you need to provide the companion object in your trait in some other way, for example as an abstract field.

Here's a version of what I believe you want to do:

```
abstract class BaseModel[T] {
  def all: Seq[T]
}

case class Customer(email: String, password: String)

object Customer extends BaseModel[Customer] {
  def all = List[Customer]() // have to define this
}

trait BaseCrud[T] {
  val companion : BaseModel[T]
  def table(f: T => String): String = {
    companion.all.map(f).mkString("")
  }
}

object Controller extends BaseCrud[Customer] {
  val companion = Customer
  def foo = table(_.email)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it working. Sorry about the mistakes in my code, most were caused in the stripping down for the test case. I was realizing there was a difference between companion objects and their class but couldn't work out how to pass them in as type parameters (which wasn't a very good solution).

Answer (score 2):

I think, you can use scala `self` type in `BaseCrud` trait to specify a class it should be mixed in. See [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) for details.

```
trait BaseCrud[T] {
  self: BaseModel[T] =>
  def table(f: T => String): String =
    all.map(f).mkString("")
}

object Controller extends BaseModel[Customer] with BaseCrud[Customer]{
  def foo = table(_.email)
}
```

Comment: Thanks works but I need my BaseModel[T] mixed into the Customer object for other parts of the code. But I put this technique to use in the same code to access the Controller from the BaseCrud[T].