# Usefulness of explicitly-typed self references in the Cake Pattern

Tags: scala, cake-pattern

It seems that the most common use of Scala's [explicitly-typed self references](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124) is in the "[Cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/)," in which a module's dependencies are declared like:

```
class Foo { this: A with B with C =>
  // ...
}
```

In general, ignoring the cake pattern for a moment, `A`, `B` and `C` can refer to *any* type-level thing, such as a type parameter:

```
class Outer[A, B, C] {
  class Inner { this: A with B with C =>
    // ...
  }
}
```

... or an abstract type member:

```
class Outer {
  type A
  type B
  type C
  class Inner { this: A with B with C =>
    // ...
  }
}
```

In neither of these cases could we have written `abstract class Inner extends A with B with C`, because `A`, `B` and `C` are not known to be traits. The explicitly-typed self references are necessary here. However, I've only ever seen the cake pattern done with traits:

```
trait A { def a }
trait B { def b }
trait C { def c }
class Foo { this: A with B with C =>
  // ...
}
```

In this case, we can instead write `abstract class Foo extends A with B with C` directly, which if I'm not mistaken has the same meaning. Am I correct? If not, then how do they differ; and if so, why does everybody seem to use the explicitly-typed self reference regardless?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between scala self-types and trait subclasses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

Comment: @sschaef different question there, but one of Daniel's comments under his answer might be the answer I'm looking for... Seems to be analogous maybe to `public` inheritance vs. `protected` inheritance in C++?

Comment: For me both questions seem to want to know the same thing - they differ in abstract classes vs traits which is the same direction. Or did I fundamentally understand something wrong?

Comment: Btw, I don't know C++. Can't say if there is a analogy to its public/protected inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like there are two main differences I overlooked:

1. Although both the explicit self-type annotation and the simple `extends` keyword describe an "is-a" relationship between two types, that relationship is not externally visible in the former case:

   ```
   scala> trait T
   defined trait T

   scala> class C { this: T => }
   defined class C

   scala> implicitly[C <:< T]
   <console>:10: error: Cannot prove that C <:< T.
   ```

   This is a good thing, because in the cake pattern you don't want your "module" object to be inadvertently, polymorphically used as one of the traits on which it depends.
2. [As noted explicitly by Mushtaq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1991378/1011414) and [indirectly by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11476927/1011414), dependencies can be cyclic when using self-type annotations. Cyclic dependencies are very common, and not necessarily bad (assuming the interdependent components don't require each other for initialization, or that we can somehow [tie the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) between them), so this is another clear benefit of self-type annotations over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use inheritance, you make decisions about initialization order. When you use self types, you leave that open.

There are other differences, but I think most of them are implementation details and may disappear. I *know* some of them are.

Comment: I'd have preferred "when you use inheritance, God kills a kitten."

Comment: On a more serious note... I don't understand why you mention path-dependent types here; do they make a difference in the choice between using `extends` vs. self types?

Comment: @mergeconflict Thinking back, the classes actually being extended are often top level -- the nested ones are usually referred to inside them. I think I'm going to drop that from the answer, but the initialization order is a concern. There are other differences, but I have been corrected before by higher powers to the effect that many of them are implementation details instead of by design.