# Scala self type annotation vs 'with' mix in

Tags: scala, traits, self-type

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between scala self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

I can't get the the difference between the two following code blocks:

```
    // Trait B is mixed in and creates a dependency on it
    trait A extends C with B { 
       ...
    }

    // Trait B is put in scope and also creates a dependency on it
    trait A extends C {
       self: B =>
    ...
    }
```

I'm asking from a design perspective.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Comment: But in this case, there's no inheritance relationship...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the self-type you constrain the `trait` to be used only when the specified self-type is satisfied by the other types with which it is mixed. You don't get an inheritance relationship between the `trait` being defined and the declared self-type. An implication of this is that the trait itself, as a static type in isolation, is not on its own publicly substitutable for the self-type. (It has been likened to C++ private inheritance, but it's a weak analogy).

Comment: I've updated my example, I missed something. So in current case, do they provide the same design.

Comment: @JorgeOlmos: I'm not sure what you mean by "provide the same design," but they certainly do not have the same semantics in Scala.

Comment: you're right, I was confused, Thanks!