# What does class Foo {this: SomeTraitType => mean?

Tags: oop, scala, traits

I have this question based on the Akka Concurrency pre-print (the final version isn't available yet), where this is used without explanation.

In version 1 of the class, they have:

```
class Altimeter extends Actor with ActorLogging with EventSource{
...
}
```

The claim is that Altimeter is now closely couple with EventSource, so testing Altimeter requires also testing EventSource. The suggested change to fix that is as follows:

```
--- a/src/main/scala/Altimeter.scala
+++ b/src/main/scala/Altimeter.scala
@@ -9,9 +9,10 @@ import  scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
 object Altimeter{
   case class RateChange(amount: Float) //sent to Altimeter
   case class AltitudeUpdate(altitude: Double)
+  def apply() = new Altimeter with ProductionEventSource
 }

-class Altimeter extends Actor with ActorLogging with EventSource{
+class Altimeter extends Actor with ActorLogging{ this: EventSource =>
   import Altimeter._

   val ceiling = 43000       //feet
diff --git a/src/main/scala/EventSource.scala b/src/main/scala/EventSource.scala
index 1fd5578..ded4f38 100755
--- a/src/main/scala/EventSource.scala
+++ b/src/main/scala/EventSource.scala
@@ -8,7 +8,12 @@ object EventSource{
   case class UnregisterListener(listener: ActorRef)
 }

-trait EventSource { this: Actor =>
+trait EventSource{
+  def sendEvent[T](event: T): Unit
+  def eventSourceReceive: Actor.Receive
+}
+
+trait ProductionEventSource { this: Actor =>
   import EventSource._
```

My first problem is that I don't understand what `this: SomeTraitType =>` accomplishes. Is it literally saying that the class is of type SomeTraitType?

My second question is, what's the difference between that and using `extends SomeTraitType`, and why is it advantageous? Perhaps that would be obvious if I knew it the former meant.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That notation (`this: EventSource => ...`) is called a "self-type annotation" and it constrains the way a trait may be mixed into another inheritance structure. Any name (not just `this`) may be used. `self` is another common one.

This use is, more or less, the Cake pattern (or a simplification thereof). With that terminology, you can find many resources that will help explain its use.

Another use of a self-type annotation (usually unconstrained, simply `self => ...`) creates an alias for `this` that can be used in a nested scope (nested class) where the outer `this` is masked.