# Self in trait invisible from outside the trait?

Tags: scala

```
trait A { def someMethod = 1}
trait B { self : A => }

val refOfTypeB : B = new B with A

refOfTypeB.someMethod
```

The last line results in a type mismatch error. My question is: why it's impossible to reach the method (of A) when it's given that B is also of type A?

Answer (score 2):

So `B` is not also of type `A`. The self type annotation that you've used here indicates specifically that `B` does not extend `A` but that instead, wherever `B` is mixed in, `A` must be mixed in at some point as well. Since you downcast `refOfTypeB` to a `B` instead of `B with A` you don't get access to any of type `A`'s methods. Inside of the implementation of the `B` trait you can access `A`'s methods since the compiler knows that you'll at some point have access to `A` in any implemented class. It might be easier to think about it as `B` depends on `A` instead of `B` is an `A`.

For a more thorough explanation see this answer: [What is the difference between self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

Comment: Yeah I get that it's how it works now, I'm just disappointed that they didn't decide to make outside references (like in my example) work as well. Since the compiler knows that B will always have all properties of type A, they could have made them accessible from outside (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: Think of this as dependency injection. If you inject a database connection as a dependency to `B` you wouldn't expect `B` to also have all methods of your database connection publicly available? If you want these methods public why not just use `trait B extends A` instead of self types?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it because in my case A is a class.

Comment: Actually, your last comment led me to reevaluate the need for the classes (all of them abstract) and it turns out that whatever I wanted to achieve with abstract classes, I can do with traits (and in more conscise way!). I wonder if abstract classes are in Scala just for Java interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you declare refOfTypeB, you have type B specified but not type B with A.

The self => syntax allow you to access the properties of A within B and pass the compilation.

However, in the runtime, refOfTypeB is not recognize as B with A and the compiler doesn't necessarily have the function map correctly.

So, the correct syntax should be:

```
trait A { def someMethod = 1}
trait B { self : A => }

val refOfTypeB : B with A = new B with A

refOfTypeB.someMethod //1
```

Indeed, this is more expressive in terms of explaining with what refOfTypeB exactly is.

This is the somehow the boilerplate of cake patterns.