# What is the implicit resolution sequence in this "simple" ScalaZ tutorial code example?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scalaz

The code snippet below is taken from [this](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/a+Yes-No+typeclass.html) ScalaZ tutorial.

I cannot figure out how the implicit resolution rules are applied when evaluating `10.truthy` at the bottom of the code example.

Things that - I think -  I do understand are the following:

1) The implicit value `intCanTruthy` is an instance of an anonymous subclass of `CanTruthy[A]` which defines the `truthys` method for `Int`-s according to :

```
scala> implicit val intCanTruthy: CanTruthy[Int] = CanTruthy.truthys({
         case 0 => false
         case _ => true
       })
intCanTruthy: CanTruthy[Int] = CanTruthy$$anon$1@71780051
```

2) The `toCanIsTruthyOps` implicit conversion method is in scope when evaluating `10.truthy`, so the compiler will try to use this implicit conversion method when it sees that `Int` does not have a `truthy` method. So the compiler will try to look for some implicit conversion method which converts `10` into an object that does have a `truthy` method and therefor it will try `toCanIsTruthyOps` to this conversion that.

3) I suspect that the implicit value `intCanTruthy` somehow might be used when the compiler tries the `toCanIsTruthyOps` implicit conversion on `10`.

But this is where I really get lost. I just don't see how the implicit resolution process proceeds after this. What happens next ? How and Why ?

In other words, I don't know what is the implicit resolution sequence that allows the compiler to find the implementation of the `truthy` method when evaluating `10.truthy`.

**Questions**:

How will `10` be converted to some object which does have the correct `truthy` method ?

What will that object be ?

Where will that object come from?

Could someone please explain, **in detail**, how the implicit resolution takes place when evaluating `10.truthy` ?

How does the  [self-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) `{ self => ...` in `CanTruthy` play a role in the implicit resolution process ?

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait CanTruthy[A] { self =>
  /** @return true, if `a` is truthy. */
  def truthys(a: A): Boolean
}
object CanTruthy {
  def apply[A](implicit ev: CanTruthy[A]): CanTruthy[A] = ev
  def truthys[A](f: A => Boolean): CanTruthy[A] = new CanTruthy[A] {
    def truthys(a: A): Boolean = f(a)
  }
}
trait CanTruthyOps[A] {
  def self: A
  implicit def F: CanTruthy[A]
  final def truthy: Boolean = F.truthys(self)
}
object ToCanIsTruthyOps {
  implicit def toCanIsTruthyOps[A](v: A)(implicit ev: CanTruthy[A]) =
    new CanTruthyOps[A] {
      def self = v
      implicit def F: CanTruthy[A] = ev
    }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait CanTruthy
defined module CanTruthy
defined trait CanTruthyOps
defined module ToCanIsTruthyOps
```

Trying out the type class on `10` :

```
scala> import ToCanIsTruthyOps._
import ToCanIsTruthyOps._

scala> implicit val intCanTruthy: CanTruthy[Int] = CanTruthy.truthys({
         case 0 => false
         case _ => true
       })
intCanTruthy: CanTruthy[Int] = CanTruthy$$anon$1@71780051

scala> 10.truthy
res6: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, thanks for pasting a fully self-contained example.

> How will `10` be converted to some object which does have the correct `truthy` method ?

When calling a method on a value whose type `A` does not supply that method, an *implicit conversion* must kick in, i.e. there must be a method or function in scope with signature `A => B` with `B` having the method in question (`truthy`). In the case of a conversion method, it may ask for additional *implicit parameters* which would be looked up accordingly.

The conversion method is `toCanIsTruthyOps`, made available by importing the contents of `ToCanIsTruthyOps`. The type `B` in the aforementioned sentence then is `CanTruthyOps`, and the conversion method is `toCanIsTruthyOps`. It may be invoked by the compiler as long as the implicit type-class evidence parameter `CanTruthy` is found. So since `type A = Int`, the compiler has to find an implicit value of type `CanTruthy[Int]` if the call `10.truthy` is going to be successful.

It looks for such a value in several places. It could be in the companion object of `Int` (that doesn't exist) or the companion object of `CanTruthy`, or it was explicitly imported into the current scope. Here, the last case is used. You explicitly created the implicit value `intCanTruthy`, and that value is now found. And that's it.

> What will that object be ?

There will be a temporary instance of `CanTruthyOps` whose mere purpose is to call `truthys` on the evidence type class value (your `intCanTruthy` here).

> Where will that object come from?

It is found in the look-up for implicit conversions `Int => CanTruthyOps[Int]`. The conversion performs the instantiation of that object.

> Could someone please explain, in detail, how the implicit resolution takes place when evaluating `10.truthy` ?

See answer to first question above. Or as explicit code:

```
type A = Int
val v: A = 10
val ev: CanTruthy[A] = intCanTruthy
val ops: CanTruthyOps[A] = ToCanIsTruthyOps.toCanIsTruthyOps(v)(ev)
ops.truthy
```

> How does the self-type `{ self => ...` in `CanTruthy` play a role in the implicit resolution process ?

It has nothing to do with the implicit resolution. Indeed, in your example of the `trait CanTruthy`, the `self` acts as an alias for `this` and isn't even used, so you could just remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed and valuable answer!

Comment: Why is the `implicit` keyword needed in the line `implicit def F: CanTruthy[A]` in the trait declaration of  `CanTruthyOps` ? I don't see how that is needed in the implicit resolution here. Does `F` really need to be declared to be implicit ?

Comment: The implicit with `def F` is completely unnecessary here. It might have some use somewhere else in Scalaz. I understand it looks confusing here. Just ignore it.

Comment: I removed the implicit keyword from there and this example still compiles and I get the same result.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation on this.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of the method that converts any `A` to `CanTruthyOps[T]` which has the `truthy` method is:

```
implicit def toCanIsTruthyOps[A](v: A)(implicit ev: CanTruthy[A])
```

this means that it doesn't convert just any `A` but only those for which there is a `CanTruthy[A]` defined, which is what the `implicit ev` parameter is for. This means that, as part of the process of mapping `10` to something that has a `.truthy` method, also `intCanTruthy` is looked up before the wrapping is done. So by the time that `10` has been implicitly converted to something with a `truthy` method, the `intCanTruthy` instance will have already been looked up and stored away as the `F` attribute of the `CanTruthyOps`:

```
implicit def F: CanTruthy[A] = ev
```

(actually I don't know why that `implicit` is necessary there; `truthy()` will turn to `F` explicitly.

```
F.truthys(self)
```

As to how exactly implicit resolution works, you're better off looking up documentation that describes the process in detail.