# Scala type inference working with Slick Table

Tags: scala, types, slick, type-inference

Have such models (simplified):

```
case class User(id:Int,name:String)
case class Address(id:Int,name:String)
...
```

Slick (2.1.0 version) table mapping:

```
class Users(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[User](_tableTag, "users") with WithId[Users, User] {`
  val id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  ...
}
trait WithId[T, R] {
  this: Table[R] =>
  def id: Column[Int]
}
```

Mixing trait `WithId` I want to implement generic DAO methods for different tables with column `id: Column[Int]`  (I want method `findById` to work with both `User` and `Address` table mappings)

```
trait GenericSlickDAO[T <: WithId[T, R], R] {
  def db: Database

  def findById(id: Int)(implicit stk: SlickTableQuery[T]): Option[R] = db.withSession { implicit session =>
    stk.tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).list.headOption
  }

trait SlickTableQuery[T] {
  def tableQuery: TableQuery[T]
}

object SlickTableQuery {
  implicit val usersQ = new SlickTableQuery[Users] {
    val tableQuery: Table Query[Users] = Users
  }
}
```

The problem is that `findById` doesn't compile:

> Error:(13, 45) type mismatch;
>    found   : Option[T#TableElementType]  required: Option[R]
>       stk.tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).list.headOption

As I see it `T` is of type `WithId[T, R]` and at the same time is of type `Table[R]`. Slick implements the `Table` type such that if `X=Table[Y]` then `X#TableElementType=Y`.

So in my case `T#TableElementType=R` and `Option[T#TableElementType]` should be inferred as `Option[R]` but it isn't. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption about `WithId[T, R]` being of type `Table[R]` is wrong. The self-type annotation in `WithId[T, R]` just requires a `Table[R]` to be mixed in, but that doesn't mean that `WithId[T, R]` is a `Table[R]`.

I think you confuse the declaration of `WithId` with instances of `WithId` which eventually need to be an instance of a `Table`.

Your upper type bound constraint in the `GenericSlickDAO` trait also doesn't guarantee you the property of `WithId` to be an instance of `Table`, since any type is a subtype of itself.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) question for a more elaborate explanation about the differences between self-types and subtypes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using play-slick and I tried to do exactly like you, with a trait and using `self-type` without success.

But I succeeded with the following:

```
import modelsunscanned.TableWithId

import scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend
import scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._


/**
 * @author Sebastien Lorber (lorber.sebastien@gmail.com)
 */
package object models {

  private[models] val Users = TableQuery(new UserTable(_))
  private[models] val Profiles = TableQuery(new ProfileTable(_))
  private[models] val Companies = TableQuery(new CompanyTable(_))
  private[models] val Contacts = TableQuery(new ContactTable(_))


  trait ModelWithId {
    val id: String
  }


  trait BaseRepository[T <: ModelWithId] {
    def tableQuery: TableQuery[TableWithId[T]]


    private val FindByIdQuery = Compiled { id: Column[String] =>
      tableQuery.filter(_.id === id)
    }


    def insert(t: T)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = {
      tableQuery.insert(t)
    }


    def getById(id: String)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session): T = FindByIdQuery(id).run.headOption
      .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Could not find entity with id=$id"))

    def findById(id: String)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session): Option[T] = FindByIdQuery(id).run.headOption




    def update(t: T)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session): Unit = {
      val nbUpdated = tableQuery.filter(_.id === t.id).update(t)
      require(nbUpdated == 1,s"Exactly one should have been updated, not $nbUpdated")
    }

    def delete(t: T)(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = {
      val nbDeleted = tableQuery.filter(_.id === t.id).delete
      require(nbDeleted == 1,s"Exactly one should have been deleted, not $nbDeleted")
    }

    def getAll(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session): List[T] = tableQuery.list

  }

}


// play-slick bug, see https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/227
package modelsunscanned {
   abstract class TableWithId[T](tableTag: Tag,tableName: String) extends Table[T](tableTag,tableName) {
    def id: Column[String]
  }
}
```

I give you an exemple usage:

```
object CompanyRepository extends BaseRepository[Company] {
  // Don't know yet how to avoid that cast :(
  def tableQuery = Companies.asInstanceOf[TableQuery[TableWithId[Company]]] 

  // Other methods here
  ...
}




case class Company(
                    id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString,
                    name: String,
                    mainContactId: String,
                    logoUrl: Option[String],
                    activityDescription: Option[String],
                    context: Option[String],
                    employeesCount: Option[Int]
                    ) extends ModelWithId


class CompanyTable(tag: Tag) extends TableWithId[Company](tag,"COMPANY") {
  override def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
  def mainContactId = column[String]("main_contact_id", O.NotNull)
  def logoUrl = column[Option[String]]("logo_url", O.Nullable)
  def activityDescription = column[Option[String]]("description", O.Nullable)
  def context = column[Option[String]]("context", O.Nullable)
  def employeesCount = column[Option[Int]]("employees_count", O.Nullable)
  //
  def * = (id, name, mainContactId,logoUrl, activityDescription, context, employeesCount) <> (Company.tupled,Company.unapply)
  //
  def name_index = index("idx_name", name, unique = true)
}
```

---

Note that [active-slick](https://github.com/strongtyped/active-slick) is also using something similar

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out a lot. It's a pretty simple example of a genericdao https://gist.github.com/lshoo/9785645

```
package slicks.docs.dao

import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.driver._


trait Profile {
  val profile: JdbcProfile
}

trait CrudComponent {
  this: Profile =>

  abstract class Crud[T <: Table[E] with IdentifiableTable[PK], E <: Entity[PK], PK: BaseColumnType](implicit session: Session) {

    val query: TableQuery[T]

    def count: Int = {
      query.length.run
    }

    def findAll: List[E] = {
      query.list()
    }

    def queryById(id: PK) = query.filter(_.id === id)

    def findOne(id: PK): Option[E] = queryById(id).firstOption

    def add(m: E): PK = (query returning query.map(_.id)) += m 

    def withId(model: E, id: PK): E 

    def extractId(m: E): Option[PK] = m.id

    def save(m: E): E = extractId(m) match {
      case Some(id) => {
        queryById(id).update(m)
        m
      }
      case None => withId(m, add(m))
    }

    def saveAll(ms: E*): Option[Int] = query ++= ms

    def deleteById(id: PK): Int = queryById(id).delete

    def delete(m: E): Int = extractId(m) match {
      case Some(id) => deleteById(id)
      case None => 0
    }

  }
}

trait Entity[PK] {
  def id: Option[PK]
}

trait IdentifiableTable[I] {
  def id: Column[I]
}


package slicks.docs

import slicks.docs.dao.{Entity, IdentifiableTable, CrudComponent, Profile}


case class User(id: Option[Long], first: String, last: String) extends Entity[Long]

trait UserComponent extends CrudComponent {
  this: Profile =>

  import profile.simple._

  class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") with IdentifiableTable[Long] {

    override def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def first = column[String]("first")
    def last = column[String]("last")

    def * = (id.?, first, last) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

  }

  class UserRepository(implicit session: Session) extends Crud[UsersTable, User, Long] {

    override def query = TableQuery[UsersTable]

    override def withId(user: User, id: Long): User = user.copy(id = Option(id))
  }
}
```