# Understanding use of "this: SomeClassOrTrait =>" in Scala

Tags: scala

What is "**this: Core =>**" in CoreActors below.

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.demo.service.DemoService
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

trait Core {
  implicit def system: ActorSystem
}

trait BootedCore extends Core {
  implicit lazy val system = ActorSystem("demo-microservice-system")

  sys.addShutdownHook(system.shutdown())
}

trait ConfigHolder {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
}

trait CoreActors extends ConfigHolder {
  this: Core =>

  val demoService = system.actorOf(
    DemoService.props("identity"), "DemoService")

  val services: Services = Map(
    "demoService" -> demoService
  )
}
```

Comment: This is a self-type annotation, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses

Comment: It's a core scala, not something from Akka, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-scala-self-types-and-trait-subclasses?rq=1