# Enforcing the type of a Scala trait using a generic

Tags: scala, generics, traits

Essentially, I am trying to do the following:

```
trait Foo[T] extends T {
  def json: Writes[T]
  def bar: String = {
    Json.toJson[T](this)(json).toString
  }
}
```

I want the compiler to enforce that any class using trait Foo is of type T. Unfortunatly, 'extends T' is not valid. Right now, the best I can do is the following:

```
trait Foo[T] extends T {
  def json: Writes[T]
  def bar: String = {
    Json.toJson(this.asInstanceOf[T])(json).toString
  }
}
```

But obviously, the compiler isn't enforcing anything. Is there anyway to achieve what I want?

Comment: How does it make sense to have Foo[T] extends T, would you have e.g. Foo<String> extends String in Java? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [*self type*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1990948/334519) to require that any class extending `Foo[T]` also be an instance of `T`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

trait Foo[T] { self: T =>
  def json: Writes[T]
  def bar: String = Json.toJson[T](self)(json).toString
}
```

You can use whatever name you want in place of `self` (which is just a common convention).