# How to explain TreeNode type restriction and self-type in Spark's TreeNode?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, treenode, self-type

From the definition of [TreeNode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode.scala#L81) in Spark SQL:

```
abstract class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] extends Product {
  self: BaseType =>
  ...
}
```

What does it say about the subtypes of `TreeNode` and `BaseType`? What's acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Self-types

First, have a look at so called **self-types**: The blog of Andrew Rollins gives a nice intro on [Self Type Annotations vs. Inheritance](http://www.andrewrollins.com/2014/08/07/scala-cake-pattern-self-type-annotations-vs-inheritance/).

Basically, a self type, written as

```
trait Foo { self: SomeType =>
  ...
}
```

says, the trait `Foo` can only be mixed in a class which also implements `SomeType`. The difference between inheritance and self-type is also nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses).

Often, self-types are used for [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), such as in the [Cake Pattern](http://scala.sygneca.com/patterns/component-mixins).

## Type-restrictions

Given the type definition:

```
class TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]] {
  self: BaseType with Product =>
  // ...
}
```

1. The definition `TreeNode[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]]` says: TreeNode is typed such that the type parameter `BaseType` is at least (in the sense of sub-classing) also a `TreeNode[BaseType]`. Speaking roughly that means: The type-parameter must also be a `TreeNode` itself.
2. The self-type here demands, that a subclass of `TreeNode` is only "allowed" if it also provides a `Product`.

## Concrete examples

### Example 1

```
class IntTreeNode extends TreeNode[Int] {}
```

**does not** compile due to:

1. The type argument `Int` does not conform to class `TreeNode`'s type parameter bounds, i.e. `[BaseType <: TreeNode[BaseType]]`
2. Illegal inheritance due to self-type restriction.

### Example 2

```
class IntTreeNode2 extends TreeNode[IntTreeNode2]
```

**does not** compile due to:

1. Illegal inheritance due to self-type restriction.

### Example 3

```
class TupleTreeNode extends TreeNode[TupleTreeNode] with Product1[Int] {
  // implementation just to be a `Product1` 
  override def _1: Int = ???
  override def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = ???
}
```

**does** compile due to:

1. **type constraint** on `BaseType` and **self-type** are both fulfilled. So, this is what the original definition requires.

### Remark

Also an example similar to yours (Catalyst) is given on [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html)