# Get values of all variables in a case class without using reflection

Tags: scala

Is there an easy way to get the values of all the variables in a case class without using reflection. I found out that reflection is slow and should not be used for repetitive tasks in large scale applications.

What I want to do is override the `toString` method such that it returns tab-separated values of all fields in the case class in the same order they've been defined in there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Are you looking for a generic way to do it to any case class or to a specific case class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use its extractor:

```
case class A(val i: Int, val c: String) {
  override def toString = A.unapply(this).get.toString // TODO: apply proper formatting.
}

val a = A(5, "Hello world")
println(a.toString)
```

Comment: It looks good, other than it gives back a tuple on which I cannot do a `mkString("\t")`. I am looking for tab separated values in my string.

Comment: Try `A.unapply(this).get.productIterator.mkString("\t")`

Comment: And this is not as slow as reflection? I am sorry, I don't really know how `unapply` works.

Comment: Nope. `unapply` is extractor that is automatically generated for each case class. For the class I've provided it will look like: `def unapply(a: A) = Some((a.i, a.c))` You can read here about extractors: http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112 In short it is how pattern matching works. Reflection is not used here, this `unapply` is generated during compile-time

Answer (score 13):

> What I want to do is override the `toString` method such that it returns tab-separated values of all fields in the case class in the same order they've been defined in there.

Like this?

```
trait TabbedToString {
  _: Product =>

  override def toString = productIterator.mkString(s"$productPrefix[", "\t", "]")
}
```

**Edit:** Explanation—We use a [self-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) here, you could also write `this: Product =>` or `self: Product =>`. Unlike inheritance it just declares that this type (`TabbedToString`) must occur mixed into a `Product`, therefore we can call `productIterator` and `productPrefix`. *All case classes automatically inherit the `Product` trait.*

Use case:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) extends TabbedToString

Person("Joe", 45).toString
```

Comment: What's does the `_: Product =>` part do?

Comment: Nicely explained. You've got my upvote but the other person answered first, which I selected as the right answer. Anyway, it doesn't look like you need the rep :)