# Trait that extends a type argument

Tags: scala, subclass, generic-type-argument

I tried that:

```
sealed trait AorB
trait A extends AorB { def apiA:... }
trait B extends AorB { def apiB:... }
```

and in another file:

```
trait C[AB<:AorB] extends AB
```

But get an `error: class type required but AB found`

What I actually want to do is to say that subclasses of `C` should implements either `A` or `B` (and not `AorB` which is used as some kind of trait-Enum, i.e. either A or B).

Can I do that, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in one of the "related questions" proposed by SO (which had an unrelated title :-):

```
sealed trait AorB
trait A extends AorB { def apiA:... }
trait B extends AorB { def apiB:... }

trait C { this: AorB => }
```

#### Edit

I use this to have some king of cartesian product of types:

```
sealed trait CorD { this: AorB => }
trait C extends CorD { this: AorB => def apiC:... }
trait D extends CorD { this: AorB => def apiD:... }
// the "this: AorB =>" need to be repeated
```

So (in other files again), we can define:

```
case class AwithC extends A with C { 
  def apiA:....
  def apiC:....
}
```

And so on with any combination of `AorB x CorD`