# Scala: self => What does it mean?

Tags: scala

When I look at the code of `scala.collection.TraversableLike` I see that it starts with `self =>`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's something called `self-type annotation` and allows two things:

- aliasing `this` (helpful in nested classes or traits, where `this` would give you the access to the inner class, and `self` would give you the access to the outer class),
- specifying
  additional requirements about `this` (it works very similar to
  inheritance then, you can see examples and differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses))

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example of (2) - specifying additional requirements about `this`?

Comment: There are a few really good examples here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses .
If you'll have any further questions, feel free to ask ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is usually used as an alias to "**this**" variable. Why do you even need this? Consider a simple example:

```
class A{
  self=>
  def generate = 5

  class B{
    def generate:Int = {
      self.generate+5
    }
  }
  def o = (new B).generate
}

val a = new A

a.o
```

If you change "**self**" to "**this**" you will get StackOverflowException. Why? Because "**this.generate**" inside the nested class refers to the method "**generate**" of class **B**. So in order to get access to the method "**generate**" of class A we created an alias to "this".
You could have also wrote:

```
A.this.generate
```

instead. And it works too.

You might me also interested in this article. 
http://www.markthomas.info/blog/92

Comment: In this particular case the equivalent of `B` is `WithFilter`.