# Types, self-typing, and type aliasing

Tags: scala

```
object Test {
  trait Foo
  trait Bar {
    def someMethod(): Unit
    val someValue: String
  }

  trait Runner {
    protected type A <: Foo

    def run(a: A): Unit
  }

  trait Runner2 {
    this: Runner =>

    protected type A <: Foo with Bar

    def run(a: A): Unit = a.someMethod()
  }
}
```

In the above example, if Runner2 is *not* self-typed as Runner, the code compiles, but if it is, it does not:

```
Error:(42, 29) value someMethod is not a member of Runner2.this.A
    def run(a: A): Unit = a.someMethod()
```

I understand this is because the self-typing causes Runner.A to "take precedence" over Runner2's override, but - why?

If I don't use the self-typing, other issues arise with concrete implementations of Runner2, since such implementations extend Runner and mix-in Runner2.

What's the best way to handle such relationships?

Comment: Why not have `Runner2 extends Runner`?

Comment: That does work.  I guess I don't understand the differences between extension and self-typing well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, the answer is right in front of you... ;-)

The error states: `value someMethod is not a member of Runner2.this.A`.

You have declared `Runner2.this` to be of type `Runner`, and `A` - as defined in trait `Runner` - does not have a method called `someMethod`. Hence the compiler error.

When you remove the self-typing, it compiles because now `Runner2`'s type `A` (of type `Foo with Bar`) does have `someMethod`.

Self-typing is essentially a statement that the associated trait will be mixed in with the specified type (or a subclass of that type) before being used. If you try to use an instance of `Runner2` (with the self-type declaration) without an instance of `Runner` being mixed-in with it, you'll get a compiler error.

For example:

```
abstract class X extends Runner2
```

will not compile because `Runner` was not mixed in. (`error: illegal inheritance; self-type X does not conform to Runner2's selftype Runner2 with Runner`.) However, this would work (in principle, however there are other problems - see below):

```
abstract class X extends Runner2 with Runner
```

What self-typing does is to give you access to the indicated type's elements. This is essential for one of the approaches to handling *dependency injection* in *Scala*. (For further information, refer to [Daniel Sobral's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses).)

However, it is `Runner` that extends `Runner2` not the other way around, so you would also discover that the compiler will complain that `Runner`'s definition of `A` has an incompatible type (since `Foo` is not a subclass of `Foo with Bar`).