# Why scala self type is not a subtype of its requirement

Tags: scala, inheritance, subtyping, self-type

I wonder what is the reasoning behind the following behaviour?

```
@ trait Bar
defined trait Bar

@ trait Foo { self: Bar => }
defined trait Foo

@ def x: Foo = ???
defined function x

@ val y: Bar = x
cmd3.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : ammonite.$sess.cmd1.Foo
 required: ammonite.$sess.cmd0.Bar
val y: Bar = x
             ^
Compilation Failed
```

AFAIU, `Foo` requires each of its subtypes to be a subtype of `Bar` so why instance of `Foo` is not a proper instance of `Bar`?

**@Edit**

Just to make the question clearer: I wonder **why** it works like that. Some possible answers are:

1. There is feature X that would not be possible with subtyping relation between those.
2. It's not true that the subtyping relation occurs (e.g. exists such instance of type `Foo` which is not the instance of type `Bar` in runtime)
3. Both scenarios (with and without subtyping relation) are valid and so the compiler team had to choose one of them. If so, was there a reason to make such a decision or it was a random choice?

It seems that at least 1) is somewhat true (hiding subtyping as implementation detail).

Comment: It's true that there is no instance of `Foo` that is not an instance of `Bar`. But would you also argue that `Foo` has to be a subtype of `Bar` in `sealed trait Foo; object A extends Foo with Bar; object B extends Foo with Bar`?

Comment: @Jasper-M that's a very good point and I probably don't want that. OTH such information could be quite useful if provided by the compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Because a selftype is an implementation detail of the `Foo` trait. You may want to implement `Foo`'s methods in terms of methods that you inherit from `Bar`, but not expose that fact to the users of your API.

Answer (score 4):

Back in 12-Mar-2006 Scala [2.0](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#changes-in-version-20-12-mar-2006--20-) introduced new keyword

```
requires
```

which was used to represent [self types](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#selftype-annotations)

```
class C requires T extends B { ... }
```

`requires` keyword was eventually [deprecated](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#changes-in-version-26-27-jul-2007--260-) on 27-Jul-2007 in Scala 2.6.0 in favour of the current self type syntax

> The `requires` clause has been deprecated; use `{ self: T =>; ... }`
> instead

however it serves as a good indicator of the design intention of the self type which was to model relationship of *"Bar requires Foo"* as opposed to *"Bar is  Foo"*, as per [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1991786/5205022)

> Now, as to what is the difference between a self type and extending a
> trait, that is simple. If you say B extends A, then B is an A. When
> you use self-types, B requires an A.

For example, *programer requires coffee*, but that does not necessarily mean programer *is* coffee (although I would not be surprised if few lost souls managed the transition).

Furthermore, bug issue [Can't access public members despite bounded 'this' #9718](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9718), which is similar to OP, was closed with [@retronym](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9718#issuecomment-292440273) (a compiler contributor) stating

> The current behaviour is as specified and actually a **feature**: the
> self type is an **implementation detail** of `Bar` that should not be
> visible to clients.

Answer (score 3):

> AFAIU, `Foo` requires each of its subtypes to be a subtype of `Bar`

No it doesn't.

```
def test[T <: Foo]: Unit = {
  implicitly[T <:< Bar] // doesn't compile
}
```

I defined a subtype of `Foo`, namely `T`, which is not a subtype of `Bar`.

This is true for subclasses.

```
class Impl extends Foo with Bar
```

If a class extends `Foo` it must extend `Bar` too.

Types and classes are different. Subtypes and subclasses are different. Subtyping and inheritance are different.

In

```
trait Foo { self: Bar => }
```

`Foo` is not a subtype of `Bar`. So you can't assign value of type `Foo` to variable of type `Bar`

```
def x: Foo = ???
val y: Bar = x // doesn't compile
```

If you want to make `Foo` a subtype of `Bar` you should use inheritance

```
trait Foo extends Bar
def x: Foo = ???
val y: Bar = x // compiles
```

or subtyping

```
type Foo <: Bar
def x: Foo = ???
val y: Bar = x // compiles
```

---

For example with self-types you can define cyclic dependencies:

```
trait Bar { self: Foo => } 
trait Foo { self: Bar => } 
class Impl extends Foo with Bar
```

If `trait A { self: B => }` implied that `A <: B` then we would have in such case that `Bar <: Foo` and `Foo <: Bar`, so `Bar =:= Foo` but it's not true, types of those traits are different.

`trait A { self: B => }` **could** mean that `A <: B` (and in such case either we wouldn't have cyclic dependencies or such traits would have equal types) but there is no **necessity** in that: if you need `A <: B` you can just declare `A extends B` while `trait A { self: B => }` has a different meaning: all **subclasses** (not subtypes) of `A` are subtypes of `B`.

Or you can limit implementation

```
trait Foo { self: Impl => } 
class Impl extends Foo
```

(`Impl` can be the only implementation of trait `Foo` like making `Foo` `sealed` with the only inheritor) but there is no **need** to make types of `Foo` and `Impl` the same.

Let's consider also the following example

```
trait NatHelper { 
  //some helper methods 
} 

sealed trait Nat { self: NatHelper => 
  type Add[M <: Nat] <: Nat 
} 

object Zero extends Nat with NatHelper { 
  override type Add[M <: Nat] = M 
} 

class Succ[N <: Nat] extends Nat with NatHelper { 
  override type Add[M <: Nat] = Succ[N#Add[M]] 
}
```

Notice that the abstract type `Nat#Add[M]` is a subtype of `Nat` but there is no **need** to make it a subtype of `NatHelper`.

Types are not necessarily connected with runtime stuff. Types can have independent meaning. For example they can be used for type-level programming when you formulate your business logic in terms of types.

---

Also there are so called tagged types (or phantom types) when you attach some information to a type

```
val x: Int with Foo = 1.asInstanceOf[Int with Foo]
```

Here we attached "information" `Foo` to number `1`. It's the same runtime number `1` but at compile time it's enriched with "information" `Foo`. Then `x.isInstanceOf[Bar]` gives `false`. I'm not sure you'll accept this example since we use `asInstanceOf` but the thing is that you can use some library function

```
val x: Int with Foo = 1.attach[Foo]
```

and you will not know that it uses `asInstanceOf` under the hood (as often happens), you will just trust its signature that it returns `Int with Foo`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218133/discussion-on-answer-by-dmytro-mitin-why-scala-self-type-is-not-a-subtype-of-its).

Comment: More info about the difference between type and set: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/what-exactly-is-the-semantic-difference-between-set-and-type https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489369/difference-between-a-type-and-a-set https://planetmath.org/11typetheoryversussettheory