# Can we reassign 'this' multiple times in a trait

Tags: scala, types, self-type

I am learning Scala and I was trying to figure out how 'self type' works for trait. 
Especially trying out to reassign the 'this' field.
 I was able to reassign 'this' once but I didn't understand how it works behind the scene. I tried to see if we can reassign this twice but it failed with a weird error.

```scala
trait DepositAccount {
    this : Account =>
    def print(): Unit = {
        println(s"Balance: $getBalance")
    }

    this: Profile =>
    def printName(): Unit = {
        println(s"Name: $getName")
    }
}
```

Following is the error.

```
';' expected but '=>' found.
this: Profile =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not a field.

You can't assign or re-assign its value but with `this: T => ...` or `any_name: T => ...` you can specify that all implementations must be subtypes of `T` (with `any_name =>` you just introduce an alias for `this`).

If you want to specify that all implementations of `DepositAccount` must be subtypes both of `Account` and `Profile` you can use intersection types (`with` in Scala 2, `&` in Scala 3)

```
trait DepositAccount {
  this: Account with Profile =>

  // ...
}
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html

[What is the difference between self-types and trait subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses)

[Difference between trait inheritance and self type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224932/difference-between-trait-inheritance-and-self-type-annotation)

[Why scala self type is not a subtype of its requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968383/why-scala-self-type-is-not-a-subtype-of-its-requirement)

[Explicit self-references with no type / difference with ''this''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073263/explicit-self-references-with-no-type-difference-with-this)

[What is more Scala idiomatic: trait TraitA extends TraitB or trait TraitA { self: TraitB => }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250374/what-is-more-scala-idiomatic-trait-traita-extends-traitb-or-trait-traita-self)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-type%2bscala?tab=Votes

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro . it worked for me. The documents shared are also very helpful