# Type declaration for this in trait body

Tags: scala, syntax

In project I work on I found following code:

```scala
trait Trait1 {
  this: Actor with Reader with Writer =>

  import ProjectDefaultLib._

  val var1: String

  // rest of the code
}
```

I couldn't find what `this: Actor with Reader with Writer =>` notation means. Please explain.

Comment: TL;DR; it means that once a you want to create a concrete type of `Trait1` you also need to extend from `Actor`, `Reader`, and `Writer`. - This is very similar to just normal inheritance / subtyping, with some minor differences for especial cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a *self-type annotation*.

From the [Tour of Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html):

> Self-types are a way to declare that a trait must be mixed into another trait, even though it doesn’t directly extend it. That makes the members of the dependency available without imports.

You can see a more complex example of how this is used [here in the Scala Book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/domain-modeling-oop.html#advanced-example-service-oriented-design).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990948/what-is-the-difference-between-self-types-and-trait-subclasses) goes more in depth with regards on when and how to use self-types instead of direct extension.